# Mobilefirst 8.0 Direct update, native app version handling issue

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have a question regarding to native app version management and direct update on Mobilefirst 8.0.

We may publish native app updates every couple weeks. We want to avoid creating a new app version on mobilefirst console (1.0, 1.1.. etc), unless the update is significant enough for us to force users to update (disabling older version on mfp console.) To achieve that, we have been updating android-versionCode and ios-CFBundleVersion in config.xml while keeping "version" the same. All works fine for previous versions of MFP (6~7). Direct update works as expected.

However, for MFP 8.0 we noticed following scenario behave abnormally.

1. Package app v1.0 with web_resource v1.0. Submit to app store.
2. Build web_resource v1.1, upload to MFP console.

--- Download app from app store, direct update triggers without a problem.

3. Package app v1.2 with web_resource v1.2. Submit to app store. (Note app "version" doesn't change, no new app created on MFP console)

--- new app goes on app store, user receives update notification and decides to ignore it.

4. Build web_resource v1.3, upload to MFP console.
5. User decides to open app and receive direct update for web_resource v1.3.
6. User finally decides to update app through app store.

--- After updating the app, the app runs web_resource v1.2 instead of v1.3. And no direct update triggered. This is not what we expected...

I understand this app version management may not be officially supported but there is an obvious reason we are doing it this way, that is to keep the MFP console app versions from going out of control.

The question becomes.. why didn't app run web_resource v1.3 after step 6? The app storage is never cleared as far as I can tell so web_resource v1.3 should still exist. Even if web_resource v1.3 is invalidated after app update, app should still starts and ping MFP server with web_resource v1.2 and triggers direct update to download web_resource v1.3.

Is there some underlying mechanism that's causing this? I suspect there is another "timestamp/last updated time" stored somewhere that's causing this. I hope this can work as it was in MFP 6~7.

Comment: This can happen if the application update in Step 3 ( v1.2) and installed in Step 6, contained a cordova-plugin-mfp update.  In case there is a mismatch (MFP checks if the three most significant digits are identical) , direct update will fail silently. Anything like this happened in your case?

Comment: There is no SDK change in this scenario

Comment: So is there anything that can be done about this? I am hoping to get better answers than L2/3's "not officially supported"...